# Using the trello API with oauth

Tags: node.js, oauth, axios, trello

When using oauth to access trello I end up getting a key pair like {"token": "tokenSecret"} (e.g. {"7089feb5de88e3e81fef1ad4e05c7690":"ec36d89fa1b9fc7ee482f73c458a0da1"})

How can I use these to make calls to the trello api with a library like axios. 
A call to trello should typically be:
https://api.trello.com/1/members/me/?key={yourAPIKey}&token={yourAPIToken} where the key is static and the token is... yeah what is the token is it the "token" or "tokenSecret" from the key pair... Or some weird compination...

I have tried with the token and I get an "invalid key"

I have used this example as inspiration: https://glitch.com/edit/#!/trello-oauth?path=server.js

Answer (score 0):

Normally the Key = Consumer key. 
And the Token = Acces Token.

You can either apply them each as a separated parameter or in your path name like you said. 
Be sure to remove the brackets { & } in your path, you just need the numbers for the key.